# Show modal after clicking on a button with asp.net core MVC

Tags: javascript, html, events, button, modal-dialog

I am trying to implement a semantic-ui modal with asp.net-core 2.0 MVC, which should show after being clicked on a button, but after trying and searching for 5 hours now I've got no solution. How can i define an eventhandling for this situation (it doesn't work with controllers too).

JavaScript

```js
<script>
        function toggle_modula(id) {
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '<div class="ui container"><div class ="ui modal"><div class="header">Hi There!</div></div></div><div class ="Content">hello World</div>';
            run();
        }
</script>
        
<script>function run() {
            $('.ui.modal').modal('toggle');
}</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://semantic-ui.com/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://semantic-ui.com/dist/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="editButton" onclick="toggle_modula('insertcodehere');">Click Me</button>


<div id="insertcodehere"></div>
```

Reference:[semantic-ui information](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal)

Thank you very much and sorry for disturbing!

Comment: I am unable to get this working in the SO snippet editor, but in codepen it seems to work fine, I don't believe it's a code problem, though you may need to reference jquery before semantic-ui. What editor are you using? Do you get any error in console?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I am working with visual studio 2017 and there is no error message. It just doesn‘t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I create a html page with the following code, it displays a button "Click me".

After clicking the button, it displays "hello World" under the button, and modal pops up with "Hi there!".
Is this the expected behavior?

The only changes are:

1. removed excess script tags
2. moved jquery script tag above semantic script

   ```
   <doctype html>
   <head>
   <!--NOTE!!!! Jquery script imported ABOVE semantic-ui to ensure it is available-->
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">
   <script src="https://semantic-ui.com/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
   <link href="https://semantic-ui.com/dist/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/></script>
   <script>
       function toggle_modula(id) {
           document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '<div class="ui container"><div class ="ui modal"><div class="header">Hi There!</div></div></div><div class ="Content">hello World</div>';
           run();
       }
       function run() {
           $('.ui.modal').modal('toggle');
   }
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <button id="editButton" onclick="toggle_modula('insertcodehere');">Click Me</button>
   <div id="insertcodehere"></div>
   </body>
   ```

I believe the order of the scripts is the key thing here. Hope this helps!
Edited to add: To test, paste the code into a text file, save as index.html and run in your browser. Isolating from your other code may help confirm what is working and what is not.